# Salesforce apex:inputText with twitter Bootstrap datepicker is not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, salesforce

This is specifically salesforce/jquery experts. 
I am trying to use twitter bootstrap datepicker on apex:inputText component.
and i have two apex:inputText components on a page.
using following code for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/js/jquery.min.js')}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js')}"></script>
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/css/bootstrap.css')}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/css/bootstrap-responsive.css')}" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="{!URLFOR($Resource.mypackage,'/datepicker/css/datepicker.css')}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

These are js and css i am using.
and following code i am using to create datepicker on the apex:inputText components

```
    <apex:form >
<b>Start Date:</b>&nbsp;
<apex:inputText label="Start Date" id="startDate" value="{!startDateString}" styleclass="editTextFieldSmall startDate"/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>End Date:</b>&nbsp;
<apex:inputText label="End Date" id="endDate" value="{!endDateString}" styleclass="editTextFieldSmall endDate" />
<input type="text" class="startDate1" value="09/01/2013"/>
<input type="text" class="startDate2" value="09/01/2013"/>
</apex:form>
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
```

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.startDate').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            });
            $('.endDate').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            });
    });
        /*$('.startDate1').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            });
            $('.startDate2').datepicker({
                format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
            });
    });*/

There are two standard input text on which datepicker works fine.
But when I use it on apex:inputText then datepicker shows up by default on load of the page. like this without clicking on the field.
[image]

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you want to prevent the datepicker loading onload of page.
To prevent standard salesforce datepicker to open onload of page add this code to your page

```
<script>
function setFocus(){}
</script>
```

Although this is not documented and might break with future release.

Comment: no this is not a standard datepicker, its a twitter bootstrap plugin.

Comment: I am using apex:inputText and not inputField. So no standard Datepicker. the value of inputText is a string. When i try use this plugin in a html page with two text fields, it works fine. But when i use it on Visualforce page. It Works but unnecessarily shows the calendar without clicking on the field. then i have to click outside of the page to hide it.

Comment: Well try it anyway, wouldn't hurt.